# How to use the Pandas 'sep' command in Google Colab?

Tags: python, pandas, google-colaboratory

So, I used Jupyter Notebook and there using the 'sep' command was pretty simple. But now I'm slowly migrating to Google Colab, and while I can find the file and build the DataFrame with 'pd.read_csv()', I can't seem to separate the columns with the 'sep = ' command!

I mounted the Drive and located the file:

```
import pandas as pd
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
with open('/content/gdrive/My Drive/wordpress/cousins.csv','r') as f:
  f.read()
```

Then I built the Dataframe:

```
df = pd.read_csv('/content/gdrive/My Drive/wordpress/cousins.csv',sep=";")
```

The dataframe is built, but it is not separated by columns! Below is a screenshot:

[Built DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adFKo.png)

Last edit: Turns out the problem was with the data I was trying to use, because it also didn't work on Jupyter. There is no problem with the 'sep' command the way it was being used!

PS: I also tried 'sep='.'' and 'sep = ','' to see if it works, and nothing.

I downloaded the data as a 'csv' table from Football-Reference, paste it on excel, saved as a csv (UTF-8), an example of the file can be found here:

[Pastebin Example File](https://pastebin.com/4RN7fmjn)

Comment: How does your data looks like? Can you update that in question?

Comment: @astro123 did just that right now!

Comment: You should try to paste data > images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

My data:

```
a,b,c
5,6,7
8,9,10
```

You don't need sep for comma separated file.

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

import pandas as pd

# suppose I have data in my Google Drive in the file path
# GoogleColaboratory/data/so/a.csv
# The folder GoogleColaboratory is in my Google Drive.
df = pd.read_csv('drive/My Drive/GoogleColaboratory/data/so/a.csv')
df.head()
```

Comment: I tried the file on Jupyter as well and it also failed, so the problem is positively with the data!

Comment: Ok, then, instead of pasting data image, it would be better if you have some sample data in the question. Open your 'cousins.csv' in a text editor, copy some lines and paste them in question. Or, you can paste your data in https://pastebin.com and share the link.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of

`df = pd.read_csv('/content/gdrive/My Drive/wordpress/cousins.csv', sep=";")`

Use

`df = pd.read_csv('/content/gdrive/My Drive/wordpress/cousins.csv', delimiter=";")`